# Why would initial Entity Framework Core add-migration skip a configuration?

Tags: entity-framework-core

When adding a migration part of the configuration seems to be skipped.

```
    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.ApplyConfiguration(new CustomerConfig());
    }

public class CustomerConfig : IEntityTypeConfiguration<Domain.Customer>
{
    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<Domain.Customer> builder)
    {
        builder.ToTable(nameof(Domain.Customer));
        builder.OwnsOne(
            o => o.Created,
            sa =>
            {
                sa.Property(p => p.Reason).HasMaxLength(255).IsUnicode(false);
            }
        );

        builder.Property(x => x.TenantId).IsRequired();
        builder.Property(x => x.RowVersion).IsRowVersion();

        builder.HasKey(x => new { x.TenantId, x.ProviderId, x.ProviderKey });
        builder.Property(x => x.ProviderKey).HasMaxLength(50).IsUnicode(false);

        builder.Property(x => x.DisplayName).HasMaxLength(255).IsUnicode(false);
    }
}
```

Is generating:

```
    protected override void Up(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
    {
        migrationBuilder.CreateTable(
            name: "Customer",
            columns: table => new
            {
                TenantId = table.Column<Guid>(nullable: false),
                RowVersion = table.Column<byte[]>(rowVersion: true, nullable: true),
                Created_SessionId = table.Column<Guid>(nullable: true),
                Created_At = table.Column<DateTimeOffset>(nullable: true),
                Created_Reason = table.Column<string>(unicode: false, maxLength: 255, nullable: true),
                ProviderId = table.Column<Guid>(nullable: false),
                ProviderKey = table.Column<string>(nullable: false),
                DisplayName = table.Column<string>(unicode: false, maxLength: 255, nullable: true)
            },
            constraints: table =>
            {
                table.PrimaryKey("PK_Customer", x => new { x.TenantId, x.ProviderId, x.ProviderKey });
            });
    }
```

The Domain.Customer.ProviderKey configuration does not seem to be applied in the migration.

Full project can be found https://github.com/CodeThumper/EFCoreMigrationSample

Comment: `Domain.Customer.ProviderKey` is a string property and it's part of the `Up` method. I don't quite understand how its "configuration does not seem to be applied".

Comment: ProviderKey = table.Column<string>(nullable: false) - No maxLength and no unicode: false.

Comment: builder.Property(x => x.ProviderKey).HasMaxLength(50).IsUnicode(false); DOES NOT EQUAL ProviderKey = table.Column<string>(nullable: false)